# Count dir and rename multiple uploaded files on upload.

Tags: php, file-upload, count, rename, dir

I'm trying to upload multiple files (imgs) from a form and I want to get the count of the directory they will be uploaded to then rename them accordingly. 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg and so on depending on how many are uploaded. The closest I've come is getting it to rename and upload first file.

```
<?php
$foldername = $_POST['stock'];

$path = 'vehicles/' . $foldername;
mkdir($path);
?>

<?php
$valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "zip", "bmp");
$max_file_size = 10240*1000; //100 kb
$path = "vehicles/$stock/"; // Upload directory
$count = 0;

$directory = "vehicles/$stock/";
$filecount = 0;
$files = glob($directory . "jpg");
if ($files){
  $filecount = count($files);
}

if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
  // Loop $_FILES to execute all files
  foreach ($_FILES['files']['name'] as $f => $name) {     
    if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$f] == 4) {
      continue; // Skip file if any error found
    }        
    if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$f] == 0) {            
      if ($_FILES['files']['size'][$f] > $max_file_size) {
        $message[] = "$name is too large!.";
        continue; // Skip large files
      }
      elseif( ! in_array(pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION),                   $valid_formats) ){
        $message[] = "$name is not a valid format";
        continue; // Skip invalid file formats
      }
      else{ 
        // No error found! Move uploaded files 
        $ext = pathinfo($_FILES['files']['name'][$f], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $uniq_name = uniqid() . '.' .'jpg';
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$f], $path .              $uniq_name);
        $count++; // Number of successfully uploaded file
      }
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your foreach is going through the first file. You want something that loops through all files.

```
foreach ($_FILES as $file_input){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I mean that your error in file name constructor:

```
   $uniq_name = ($filecount+1) . '.' .$ext;

   if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$f], $path.$uniq_name)) {
       $count++; // Number of successfully uploaded file
       $filecount++; //Folders files count
   } else {
       $message[] = "$name is not uploaded";
   }
```